# List "edit Menu" links on a custom page

Tags: 8

I am attempting to create a simple user dashboard that will let a user do things throughout the site like edit menus and content.

I would like to have a dropdown that lists all the custom menus on the site and after they select one it would take them to the edit page.

How would I go about doing this within my module?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is already done in core in D8, however not in one menu but in multiple one (in the wrapper divs of the elements).

First of all I would make a list exactly what I want to include in the custom menu (menu items edit, content edit, etc..).

And then trying to look inside the core for the existing solution for that and unite them into one menu.